# Insert a rule in Cepheus-CEP while running

Tags: fiware, complex-event-processing

I am starting to explore Fiware tools and I am testing Cepheus-CEP.
I know I can set rules and other configuration parameters in the "config.json" file that Cepheus take when I launch the service, but I don't know how to especify these rules on execution time.

For example, a "config.json" [could be](https://fiware-cepheus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/6_QueryAndCommand/index.html):

```
{
  "host":"http://localhost:8080",
  "in":[
    {
      "id":"RoomX",
      "type":"Room",
      "attributes":[
        { "name":"temperature", "type":"double" },
        { "name":"shutter", "type":"string" }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "out":[
    {
      "id":"ShutterX",
      "type":"Shutter",
      "attributes":[
        { "name":"status", "type":"string" }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "statements":[
    "INSERT INTO Shutter SELECT R.r.shutter as id, 'closed' as status FROM pattern [ every r=Room(temperature > 26.0) -> (timer:interval(5 sec) and not Room(temperature < 26.0 and id=r.id))] as R unidirectional LEFT OUTER JOIN Shutter.std:groupwin(id).std:lastevent() as S ON R.r.shutter = S.id WHERE S is null OR S.status = 'opened'",
    "INSERT INTO Shutter SELECT R.r.shutter as id, 'opened' as status FROM pattern [ every r=Room(temperature < 24.0) -> (timer:interval(5 sec) and not Room(temperature > 24.0 and id=r.id))] as R unidirectional LEFT OUTER JOIN Shutter.std:groupwin(id).std:lastevent() as S ON R.r.shutter = S.id WHERE S is null OR S.status = 'closed'"
  ]
}
```

And I want to change the statements (rules) list during execution time, Is there a query or something that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there is not a CRUD API in Cepheus CEP and from  my experience you should replace the whole config file at once.

How ever you can replace the file at running time it should works!
Tell me if you find a different approach.
Best regards!